# Is React Router automatically added on create-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you create-react-app in the inital stages of your projects, is the React Router added automatically? If not, how to included it when initializing a react project? I am working on SPA and I am trying to route different pages to the nav links.

Comment: No, it's not included by default. You'd add it much like a normal package by doing `npm install react-router --save` or `yarn add react-router`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, take a look to [package.json](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/package.json)

Answer (score 0):

no its not automatically added, you can add using the terminal
'npm i react-router-dom'. Once it added you can check it in 'package.json' file.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 2023**
`create-react-app` is deprecated and should not be used to bootstrap new projects. Better tools like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) should be used to build SPAs (Single Page Applications). Additionally, the React Core Team [recommends the use of a metaframework](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project) like Next.js or Remix.